# Merge two datasets without common column in Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have two datasets where I need to do a join/merge in Azure Data Factory, but without having a common identity column. This might be my an oversight from my side, as it should be a very trivial task to do, but I cannot seem to do it via a join or a union.

One dataset only has a couple of rows with a "name" column, let's say rows A, B, C whereas the other have thousands (1-N).

For each row in the large dataset I want A, B, C rows, so it effectively becomes:

1A
1B
1C
2A
2B
2C
...

Any help is appreciated,

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **`Custom (cross)` join type** in the Join to get the result in this case.

Follow the demonstration below:

Sample **Large Dataset(Numbers)** with numbers up to 15.

[image]

**Small Dataset(Letters)**

[image]

Now, use Join with **Large dataset as left** and **small dataset as right** and use **custom join** with the condition as `true()`.

[image]

In the Optimize of Join, select **off** at the **Broadcast** to get the above format of the data.

[image]

You can see the merge of two datasets below.

[image]

If you want the above in a single column with values like 1A,1B,1C..., first use the derived column to concat the above values and then select any column using select.

**Derived Column**

[image]

[image]

Now use select to select any column above.

**Output**

[image]